# Kivy and Buildozer crashes

Tags: kivy, mobile-application, buildozer

I have build an application with kivy and i could change it to .apk with Buildozer, But when I use it in my phone it crashes every time I open it. what should I do ?

I tried to add pillow, kivymb to the requierments but I became unable to change it to .apk.